# Cast integral array to class array

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm using a library passes me a pointer to an array of `int32_T`. I need to do some math on these numbers, but the data is actually in [Q23.8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)) format.

I created a class overloading the basic math operators, but I'm stuck with how to cast the `int32_t` array pointer to my new class -- the datatypes are different sizes. Is there a way to do force my new class to match the size of `int32_t`, or is there another way to get this done?

Note: I want to avoid copying each item of this large array, as I'm developing for a resource constrained system.

Comment: In your class have a constructor that takes a int32_t. You could then cast a single element of the array to your class in order to operate on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please note that if you are not constrained by performance, only by memory consumption, the solution suggested by @Aumnayan may be preferable for simplicity and portability.

In order to force your objects to match the size `int32_t` and alignment of Q23.8 you can use bit-fields:

```
struct Q_23_8
{
    int32_t fractional :  8;
    int32_t integral   : 23;
};

static_assert(sizeof(Q_23_8) == sizeof(int32_t), "Sizes differ!");
```

Please note that the order of fields depends on target CPU endianness; the sample is for little-endian. Also, to ensure the size of your class you may need to use your compiler's packing and alignment control capabilities (e g. `#pragma pack`).

Having `int32_t encoded[]` you can interpret it as an array of `Q_23_8` as follows:

```
Q_23_8* decoded = reinterpret_cast<Q_23_8*>(encoded);
```

Here is a complete code sample: http://ideone.com/X177fQ. I strongly suggest [reading more about bit-fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), their portability, and limitations.